# Moved data into non-existing directories

Tags: windows, python, data-recovery

I'm on Windows 10.

I wrote a script in python that was supposed to sort my downloads folder by the extensions (create  a new folder for every extension and move every file with that extension in there), but I created the folders in the wrong directory and ended up moving files into non-existing directories (using `shutil.move()`), which lead to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqZzx.png).

These files are not directories and I can't click on them to view what's inside.
I tried opening these files using

- 7zip
- explorer.exe from C:\Windows
- the windows command prompt (`cd iso` for example)

How can I turn these files into directories or undo the changes made by python?

Comment: Obviously you moved/renamed the files to their sole extension without the dot. To use the still present files (multiple files with the same extension are overwritten) rename back to any file name i.e. `ren iso some.iso` etc.

Comment: @LotPings, no, I didn't rename the files. I've moved multiple files into these "folders".

Edit: Oh.

Comment: Is there any way I can get back the overwritten files?

Comment: From your most recent backup?

Comment: Well, I don't think there was anything important in my downloads folder and I guess this is a good time to start backing up my files,